# Where is the source code for the reddit message filtering code?

Tags: reddit

I am browsing the reddit source code and would like to know specifically where the filter code is.  How does reddit's filters learn spam vs no spam etc?

Comment: I doubt, that you'll get an answer here. As we need to know reddit code very well to answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [the open-sourcing announcement post](http://www.redditblog.com/2008/06/reddit-goes-open-source.html):

> There are a few portions of the code that we're keeping to ourselves, mostly related to anti-cheating/spam protection.